# Button onClick Doesn't Work Inside Tab Layout

Tags: android

I have a TabLayout, and it have 3 tab items inside it (Accepted, Rejected, and Pending). Each of them have a recyclerlist for different status (Use 1 Adapter for it). In Tab Pending I have a button to delete the item, but the button doesnt respond to any click input. I already set the clickListener in the adapter and fragment but it still doesn't work.
I may miss something in the process, so I really need any help. Thank You.

This is the xml for list inside recycle view

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="overrideHistory"
        type="example.com.absensiapp.model.OverrideHistoryRespModel" />
    <variable
        name="onClick"
        type="example.com.absensiapp.view.listener.OverrideHistoryListener" />
</data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:onClick="@{()->onClick.onClickDeleteButton(overrideHistory.id)}"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is how i set the listener interface in adapter

```
public void setOnClick(OverrideHistoryListener listener) {
    this.overrideHistoryListener = listener;
}
```

This is how I set the listener in Fragment for the pending tab

```
public class HistoryPendingFragment extends Fragment implements OverrideHistoryListener {
    overrideHistoryListBinding.setOnClick(this);
    }
```

For the action onClick

```
public void onClickDeleteButton(String overrideId) {
    overrideViewModel.deletePendingOverride(overrideId);
}
```

This is the interface for listener

```
public interface OverrideHistoryListener {
void onClickDeleteButton(String overrideId);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
android:onClick="@{overrideHistory::onClickDeleteButton}"

public void onClickDeleteButton(view: View) {
    overrideViewModel.deletePendingOverride(overrideId);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Tried to use this in xml and it gives an error about did not match any signature in 'android:onClick'

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I forgot to initialize the Listener in the onBindViewHolder so it looks like this

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OverrideHistoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.overrideHistoryListBinding.setOnClick(this);
}
```